# Make compiler options

Tags: makefile

I am running a 32 bit machine with Ubuntu 14.04. I want to execute `sudo make` to generate a C++ compiled file (gcc-4.8.4). My Makefile is

Makefile (edited based on comments from ddumbugie):

```
CDefines = -DLINUXGXX
COMPFLAGS     =   
FlameManCC = gcc
FlameManCCOpts = -O3

OBJECTS = alligator.o
COpts = $(COMPFLAGS) $(FlameManCCOpts) $(CDefines)
CC = $(FlameManCC)
alligator.o: alligator.c
    $(CC) $(COpts) -c $< -o $@
```

Executing

```
make -n
```

gives me

```
gcc  -O3 -DLINUXGXX -c alligator.c -o alligator.o
```

But

```
sudo make -n
```

gives me

```
DLINUXGXX -c alligator.c -o alligator.o
```

Definitely command DLINUXGXX is not understood. However, I need to remain a super-user for a subsequent command executed by make. How can I resolve this?

Comment: How exactly do you run `make`?

Comment: I am newbie here. I just use make, and the Makefile is the file above

Comment: Superficially, the `sudo make -n` is behaving as if the `CC` or `FlameManCC` macros were set to empty, and as if the `FlameManCCOpts` macro is set to empty.  It's a bit tricky to see how that could happen. There is a `MAKEFLAGS` environment variable and an option `-e` that gives the environment precedence. If the root-privileged environment set those so that empty environment variables were given precedence over what's in the makefile, then you could see the result you're seeing (the missing `-` from `-DLINUXGXX` is because make treats a `-` at the start of a command as 'ignore errors'). _[…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_  But to say "this is somewhat far-fetched" is being polite about it.  I suggest that to debug further, you should do `sudo bash` or thereabouts, and examine the environment.  You might need to do it from within the makefile (add a rule: `dumpenv: ; env` which can be all on one line with the semicolon present, or split across two lines without it).  I'll also observe that you should do as little as possible as root.  It's OK to run `sudo make install` if the install directory is protected.  But you shouldn't often need to run the compilation as `root`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for this detailed comment. I will follow up the debugging with 

sudo bash

Comment: Hi, @Leaner, did you solve problem?

Comment: Hi, @Leaner, did you solve problem? I tried to reproduce what you said, I've failed.  @JonathanLeffler gave you good comments. Maybe you need to use `sudo make install` to install built binaries to system directory. And you can use GNU makefile's advanced features. `$(info...)` `$(warning...)` to debug your makefile.  [make control](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Make-Control-Functions.html),  or [debug makefile](http://www.oreilly.com/openbook/make3/book/ch12.pdf).

Comment: @ddumbugie Thanks for the feedback. I haven't had the time to check on this again. Perhaps this weekend.

Answer (score 0):

```
CDefines = -DLINUXGXX
COpts = -O3 $(CDefines)
alligator.o: alligator.c
    $(CC) $(COpts) -c $< -o $@
```

It requires `-o` compiler options.

- `$@` means the target. That is `alligator.o`.
- `$<` means the dependency. That is `alligator.c`.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a reason that the -o option must be provided and $< and $@ should be added? I am wondering because my friend does not have trouble compiling the code as provided in the question on his machine.

Comment: `-o` must not be required! But I show the common usage. Please see more complicated makefile examples. BTW, the error messages you've got is correct? Which version of make is used?

Comment: I am using make 3.81. Please see the edit to my question. I think it is the difference between make and sudo make. Any pointers on this?